# бинарный поиск, если элемент не найден java

Tags: java

как реализовать код для вывода если число не найдено. В даном коде работает если в массиве десять елементов. Как привести к общему, если колиество изменится?

```
public class BinarySearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int data[] = { 3, 6, 7, 10, 34, 56, 60 };
        int numberToFind = 10;

        int min = 0;
        int max = data.length - 1;
        int count = 0;
        while (min <= max){
            int mid = ((max - min) / 2) + min;
            if (numberToFind > data[mid])
                min = mid + 1;
            else if (numberToFind < data[mid])
                max = mid - 1;
            else if (numberToFind == data[mid]) {
                System.out.println(mid);
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (count == 4)
            System.out.println("-1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Код для для бинарного поиска нужно вывести в отдельный метод, этот метод должен возвращать числовое значение: индекс массива, в котором лежит нужное число, или "-1" если число не найдено. В методе main вы вызываете данный метод и делайте проверку полученного результата.

```
public class BinarySearch {


public static int rank(int key, int[] a){
    int min = 0;
    int max = a.length - 1;
    int count = 0;
    while (min <= max){
        int mid = ((max - min) / 2) + min;
        if (key > a[mid])
            min = mid + 1;
        else if (key < a[mid])
            max = mid - 1;
        else if (key == a[mid]) {
            return mid;
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
  return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int data[] = { 3, 6, 7, 10, 34, 56, 60 };
    int numberToFind = 10;
    int answer = rank(numberToFind, data);
    if(answer >= 0){
      System.out.println(answer);
    }else{
      System.out.println("Не найдено");
    }
  }
}
```

Насколько я знаю, этот метод должен работать для любого количества чисел. Есди вам нужен именно count, то вы можете возвращать из метода именно его, просто замените return mid; на return count;